# Is there an algorithm to calculate maximum filled percentage of circles into circle?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find out an algorithm to calculate what is the best quantity of small circles (same size) fill into a larger circle, in order to max fill the large circle, leaving the smallest unfilled space between the small ones.    WolframAlpha was able to made calculations for me, but it requires me to say how 25 million circles fill a large one.  After some million I was able to reach around 90.48%, but not sure if it is the best, since I was just guessing numbers.  Is there any practical way to calculate it?  For example, 19 is a magical one, since it put 3 in the center as a triangle, 6 around it, 12 around the 6, but lots os empty space.  I am trying to make this kind of magical geometry arrangement that keep going, more and more around, but couldn't get it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Comment: Once you get to a million small circles, most of the interior will use the [hexagonal packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing#Densest_packing). The effects around the edge become almost negligable as there a far fewer balls on the edge than on the inside, so you approach the theoretical maximum of $\pi\sqrt{3}/6 \approx 0.9069$.